# Gnuradio Buffer and sampling rate

Tags: buffer, wifi, sampling, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am kind of confused on how the ring buffers in gnuradio block works.

I am using a UHD:USRP source block with a sampling rate of 20Msps.

I believe each block has an input buffer and an output buffer that is fed into the next block.
In my flowgraph, does it mean USRP source block is pulling data from the hardware at a rate of 20Msps and the buffer will contain 20Msamples?

The output and input buffer numbers in all the blocks are made default 0.
So how does the buffer for USRP Source and the subsequent blocks look?

And in the Stream to Vector onwards does that become only 64 samples?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not the case. The source will sample at 20MSPS and put samples into the output buffer of the source block. Each buffer has a maximum size before it overflows.

In the code of each block there is a function called forecast() which tells the GNU Radio scheduler how many input samples it needs to produce a certain number of output samples. The scheduler then determines when there are enough samples for a block to produce an output. If there is enough space on the input and output buffers the scheduler calls that blocks work() function which then does the necessary signal processing at the input and produces an output. The number of samples at the input and space at the output buffers is never constant.

So in the example of the stream to vector block there may be 4096 samples at the input. It is the blocks job to check this and produce 64 vectors at the output.

GNU radio prefers that a block processes as much data as possible per call to the work function since moving samples between blocks is a costly operation.

There are some exceptions such as tagged stream blocks but for most blocks this is the basic idea.